# Use base_url() in codeigniter template library

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am using the [**Codeigniter Template Library**](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/index.html) third party plugin for templating in *Codeigniter*.

I'm having problems using built in `base_url` function in the template library's config file.

I assigned default header and footer values in the config and I don't want to use hard links.

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: wat is the value your getting in base_url() and wat is your correct your

Comment: what CI version are you using? Looking at the `library` it is outdated and works for 1.7 which is different from its 2.0+ counterparts.

Comment: does it have 2.0+ version? its perfectly working for me CI 2.1.4 except that I defined default headers in the template config file and I dont want to hard link my "HOME" "ABOUT US" etc menu that's why I'm trying to use base_url() in the templates config file. Please help. Thanks a lot! :)